# How to open any eclipse Wizard from Welcome Intro Page in eclipse plugin development

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I have created my intro page in eclipse. My introSite contains a browser and a static html page. Now only click of link in html, I want to open eclipse wizards so I used these-
http://org.eclipse.ui.intro/runAction?pluginId=org.eclipse.ui.ide&class=org.eclipse.ui.actions.QuickStartAction&standby=false

And I declared a plugin and class. I implemented IAction in the class but after opening welcome and press of the hyperlink , I am not getting anything.
What else I need to take care to achieve the same.